# `Cannot set headers after they are sent to client` error when using mysql2 async/await

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await, mysql2

I am changing my backend (switching over from Mongo to MySql). I know the error is getting thrown  because a return statement is being executed before my SQL query has finished and then when my sql query finishes, it tires to send another `res.send`, hence why I am trying to use `mysql2` with Promise wrappers to use `await` on queries in my `async` function.

I have a separate file that creates the DB connection so I can access the connection throughout my Nodejs backend:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

async function pool(){
    const pool = await mysql.createPool({
        host: "ip",
        user: "username",
        password: "password",
        database: "db"
    });
    return pool
}

exports.getConnection = async function(callback) {
    const currentPool = await pool();
    currentPool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        callback(err,conn)
    });
};
```

Then, to create a query that follows async/await:

```
sql.getConnection(async function(err, client){
        client.query(`select email from users where email = "${email}"`, function (error, result){
            if(error) return res.status(500).send('an internal db error occurred');
            // carry on with code ...
    });
});
```

I've tried using `await` on the query too:

```
await sql.getConnection(async function(err, client){
        client.query(`select email from users where email = "${email}"`, function (error, result){
            if(error) return res.status(500).send('an internal db error occurred');
            // carry on with code ...
    });
});
```

What am I missing? I haven't tired to use the normal `mysql` NPM library and make my own promise wrapper yet...

NEW CODE:

I've updated my function:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: "ip",
    user: "user",
    password: "pass",
    database: "db"
});

exports.db = (sql) => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
            if(err) return reject(err);

            conn.query(sql, (err, results, fields) => {
                conn.release()
                if(err) return reject(err)
                console.log(results)
                resolve(results);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Then I call it via:

```
try{
    const emailExisit = await sql.db(`SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = "${email}"`);
    console.log(emailExisit);
    if(emailExisit.length > 0) return res.status(422).send({"data": "", "code": "105", "message": "An account with given email already exists"});
}catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).send({"data": "", "code": "108",  "message": `There seems to be an error contacting the database. Try again later <br> ${err}`});
}
```

However, my code still continues, leaving my `emailExists` variable `undefined` (yes, it is inside an `async function`)

Comment: Show the endpoint itself too please

Comment: Your `getConnection()` function needs a redesign.  It a mess to mix callbacks and async/await the way you are doing.  Pick one model or the other and stick with it everywhere.  Since you're using mysql2, you should just be using promises and banish plain async callbacks from anywhere in your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 well I've use async callbacks everywhere in my other scripts, so whats the best way to go about this using `async/await`?

Comment: Instead of `require('mysql2')` use `require('mysql2/promise')`

Comment: You have to show us the actual request handler code (from start to finish, incuding where any response is sent) for us to know where you're making the mistake that leads to this error message.

Comment: I wrote this to help people get started with MySQL in node.js, maybe it's helpful: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Comment: @Evert thank you, that's a great article. I can do promises and awaits, I can also do SQL just fine - just not together at this present moment in time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my configuration to use MySQL with Node.js. I hope it works with you.

`/config/mysql.js`

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DB_NAME,
});

const query = (query, args = []) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      connection.query(query, args, (err, results) => {
        connection.release();
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(results);
      });
    });
  });

module.exports = { query };
```

---

`/index.js`

```
const { query } = require('./mysql');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.get('/api/v1/sum', (req, res) => {
  query('SELECT 1 + 1 as sum')
    .then(results => {
      res.json({ sum: results[0].sum });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'error msg' });
    });
});

// anther example with async
app.get('/api/v1/sum', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const results = await query('SELECT 1 + 1 as sum');
    res.json({ sum: results[0].sum });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'error msg' });
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Funny that, I have just rewritten my own function before you sent this and it looks identical to yours. However, it seems as if the `await` still isn't working on mine as the code below the `await` statement inside the `try/catch` is being run still, I've updated my question, can you take a look?

Comment: @Nathan You need to return `new Promise` in `exports.db` because exports.db now will return undefined.

Comment: Just replace `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` with `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`.

Comment: ARHHHH another simple mistake....god I hate coding. Thanks!